# Shapekeys aren't saving to the animation timeline?

Tags: animation, keyframes, shape-keys

Recently I decided to try shapekeys for facial expressions(as I used separate armatures) but I've run into the problem where I change the value, press I and hit rotlocscal(because I don't see an option for shapekey) and it doesn't change during the playing animation, staying the same.

How do I save the shapekey to the keyframe? I've tried looking it up but had no luck and I would greatly appreciate some help on this. This model is going to be imported into Unity and it's pretty important that these shapekeys work.

Also due to copyright I cannot upload any part of the model.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add keyframes by:

1. Press RMB on **Value** box and select **Insert Keyframe**.
2. Hover on **Value** box and press <kbd>I</kbd>

When keyframes created, you can edit them in **Dope sheet** or **Graph editor** like usual keyframes.

[image]

Also you can create a driver for shape keys.